# Cisco 800, RFC1483 Routing, no nat, block public IPs

Tags: cisco, ip-routing

My issue. 
IP traffic to public IPs does not work. Traffic outbound works fine.
Thus, I cannot access 91.x.x.162 from www. Thus no route for IP back to 91.x.x.162.

The connection works in part as:
Traffic from subnet works just fine, Firewall can access www with 91.x.x.162 no problem.
I can access Cisco on 91.x.x.161 from public www, no issue.

Objective Layout

www
    |
ADSL (RFC 1483} 
    |
  Cisco 877 
  Public IP: 91.x.x.161/29
{Should only route IP, no nat} 
    |
Firewall
Public IP 91.x.x.162/29
    |
Trusted LAN
10.x.x.1/24

Cisco help guide me to:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk175/tk15/technologies_configuration_example09186a008071a8bc.shtml
If I use this I cannot route traffic or out.

Current Cisco config is here:
http://justpaste.it/1kpy

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: can you post the routing table (sh ip route)